# Perl how to strip nested bbcode tags?

Tags: regex, perl, bbcode

Here is the code:

```
use perl5i::2;

my $string = '[size 9]Some larger text. [i]Italic[/i] here.[/size]And [b]bold[/b] text.';
$string =~ s/\[(.+).*?\](.+)\[\/\1\]/$2/gi;

$string->say;
```

The result is here:

> Some larger text. [i]Italic[/i] here.And bold text.

Is there a single regex to strip the tags?

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to strip all but nested bbcode tags. Is that correct?

Comment: @ikegami, I think he was saying that's the result he gets, not the result he wants.  He wants to strip all the tags.

Comment: Just as @ikegami said, strip out all bbcode tags.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is strip the tags, you don't really need to ensure that the tags match: just remove anything inside square brackets.

If checking for nesting really is important, you can simply apply your current substitution repeatedly.

Comment: Do you mean put it in a while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to strip all tags? Elements can be nested, but tags can't be nested, so there's nothing to it really.

```
s/\[[^\[\]]*\]//g;
```

Comment: This code can strip out all tags. But I just want to strip out matched tag pairs.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Parse::BBCode](https://metacpan.org/module/Parse%3a%3aBBCode)?

## Update:

You don't need to output HTML with this module. Try the following instead:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Parse::BBCode;

my %tags = map { $_ => '%s' } qw(
    b i u color size font highlight left right center indent email url thread post
    list img video code php html quote noparse attach bug PGN2 PGN3 threadvb wiki
);
my $parser = Parse::BBCode->new ( { tags => \%tags } );

my $string = '[size="9"]Some larger text. [i]Italic[/i] here.[/size]And [b]bold[/b] text.';
my $rendered = $parser->render( $string );

print "$rendered\n";
```

This way you don't have to parse any text yourself, which is a Good Thing™.

Comment: At this stage, I just read the forum posts and write to a javascitpt file, Something like XML::RSS::JavaScript. At this stage, making things clean is sufficient.

Comment: @Weiyan: See that example. It cleanly strips any tags out of the text. And you don't have to maintain a single regex...